# Inversion of the string register

Tags: postgresql, functions

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a table with serial numbers.
The serial number is like this
The serial number is like this `zHOb55Klast`,
I want to make it like this `ZhoB55kLAST`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`translate()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
select translate(
  'zHOb55Klast',
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
)
```